# Compare attributes with `value == nil`

Tags: ruby

I want to compare two object attributes with:

```
if object1.attribute1 != object2.attribute1
```

I'm also trying:

```
if (object1.attribute1 || object2.attribute1) && object1.attribute1 != object2.attribute1
```

When both attributes are `nil`, I would like to say they are equal, and not satisfy the `if` condition. But the codes above satisfy the `if` condition when both `attribute1` are `nil`.

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand, your first snippet should work perfectly fine.

Comment: If you try in Ruby `puts 'THEY ARE DIFFERNET' if nil != nil`, the program prints nothing... Are you sure both the `attribute1` are `nil' ?

Comment: You are right. When you puts object.inspect, both attributes prints nil. However, for my surprise when you do object.attribute.class one is Nil and the other one is a string like "". Thats the reason why they are differents.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunely I can't add comment because my reputation < 50.

I read [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242375/compare-attributes-with-value-nil#comment95328799_54242375). You can bang-bang you're boolean in this case.

What it means:

```
!!nil
#=> false

!!''
#=> true
```

If it's not helpful, write me and I will delete the answer.